# How to restrict access to a model property in loopback

Tags: javascript, rest, loopbackjs, loopback

I'm currently tackling access control for my loopback3 (3.26.0) api and struggle to restict access to a property for everyone except the owner.

Lets say i have a User -> Athlete relation. With Athlete having a "secretProperty".

I set secretProperty to protected and i have a

```
Athlete.afterRemote('**', function(ctx, modelInstance, next) { // i am restricting property access here, which works for direct .find()}
```

As described [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html)

But i still have the problem, that when i query

```
GET /user/{id}/athlete
```

the returned data contains my secretProperty and my hook is never called

**How do i limit access to a property across all endpoints? (basically set it to hidden but not for certain roles/users)**

Here are my model definitions:
athlete.json

```
{
  "name": "athlete",
  "plural": "athletes",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false,
      "default": ""
    },
    "mySecretProperty": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false,
      "default": 0
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  }
}
```

user.json

```
{
    "name": "user",
    "plural": "users",
    "base": "User",
    "idInjection": true,
    "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {
        "athlete": {
            "type": "hasOne",
            "model": "athlete",
            "foreignKey": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you show the files describing your Author and Book models?

Comment: i added my model definitions (and changed the name of the models to my actual ones)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a property to the Athlete model: `"protected": ["mySecretProperty"`],
and you have a set relationship between models, but not set on which fields it should run, so will not work.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#protected-properties

Comment: I have tried protected and hidden properties but they don't cover my use case. mySecretProperty should be available to SOME roles/users but not others. 

ALSO they only work if i {include: "athlete"} them but the /user/<id/athlete endpoint mentioned STILL includes mySecretProperty, which kind of defeats the purpose in my eyes. What i want to achieve is "hidden" but not for certain roles/users

Answer (score 0):

Loopback does not offer property-level security, only model-level security.  To offer property-level security we did the following:

1. Mark the property as protected
2. Create a custom end-point where users could update the protected property
3. Restricted access to the custom end-point (2) to the users or roles who could access the property.

Another option is to use the "before save" hook, validate the user and the properties to be updated.

Allt his to say that it's a manual task you have to code yourself as it is not built-into loopback